# Does a thread-safe statsd client exist?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, graphite, statsd

I need to use a thread-safe `statsd` client in a web application to monitor user threads for the statistics.  Please suggest a solution that is both thread safe and does not compromise performance.

Answer (score 2):

What about the Java client [StatsdClient.java](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/examples/StatsdClient.java) in the [examples directory](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/tree/master/examples)? They use synchronization in their Java client implementation. In the class comment is a usage example:

```
StatsdClient client = new StatsdClient("statsd.example.com", 8125);
// increment by 1
client.increment("foo.bar.baz");
```

1. `increment(String)` delegates to
2. `increment(String, int)` which delegates to
3. `increment(String, int, double)` which generates a string to invoke
4. `send(double, String...)` which finally does a call to
5. `sendTo(String)` which uses the modifier **`synchronized`**

This does apply to other methods in this class, too. 
Granted, declaring all your relevant methods as `synchronized` does not make a thread-safe class. But I believe Etsy took that into account here and made it that way.